# Calling a stored procedure from Access VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures

I need to call a stored procedure from a distant SQL Server into Access using VBA as I need to pass dynamic variables.

I call this SP using a look through query:

```
Exec GetPortfolioLookthroughMultiPeriod
  @PORTFOLIONAME ='wefb'
,@DATE= '2018-02-06'
, @TYPES='portfolio'
,@VALUES = 'portfolio'
,@ISLOOKTHROUGH=1
,@PORTFOLIOCURRENCY='PC'
,@EXPRISKLEVEL='currency'
,@NUMBEROFMONTHS=15
,@AssetClassStrategyName='fund'
,@NUMBEROFPERIODS=1
,@FREQUENCY='d'
,@ShowDetail=1
,@TableNo=6
```

Using the following ODBC Connect String:

```
ODBC;Description=RiskManager;DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;SERVER=APX-TEST01;UID=X.Tran;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=RiskManager;
```

Now my VBA code returns an error:

> Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "ODBC;Description=RiskManager;DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;SERVER=APX-TEST01;UID=X.Tran;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=RiskManager;"
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandText = "GetPortfolioLookthroughMultiPeriod"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandTimeout = 0
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@PORTFOLIONAME", adVarChar, adParamInput, 40, "wefb")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@DATE", adDBDate, adParamInput, 50, #2/5/2018#)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@TYPES", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, "portfolio")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@VALUES", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, "portfolio")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ISLOOKTHROUGH", adVarNumeric, adParamInput, 10, 1)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@PORTFOLIOCURRENCY", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, "PC")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@EXPRISKLEVEL", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, "currency")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@NUMBEROFMONTHS", adVarNumeric, adParamInput, 10, 15)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@AssetClassStrategyName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, "fund")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@NUMBEROFPERIODS", adVarNumeric, adParamInput, 10, 1)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@FREQUENCY", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, "d")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ShowDetail", adVarNumeric, adParamInput, 10, 1)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@TableNo", adVarNumeric, adParamInput, 10, 6)
    .Execute
End With
```

Comment: As they seem to be integers adInteger (with no size specified) is better than adVarNumeric.  Is there a reason for ODBC? you can simply use `"Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=APX-TEST01;Database=RiskManager;Trusted_Connection=yes;"`.  If there is still a problem you can run a profiler trace and see exactly what SQL is being sent to the server.

Comment: Use the SQL native provider (SQLOLEDB) to connect with SQL Server. If you insist on ODBC, you're restricted to using the `?` syntax for parameters, unless you set `UseNamedParameters = true`. And even then I believe it fakes it, and you need to pass parameters in exactly the declared order, *and* specify placeholders in your `CommandText` for the procedure arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot!I am happy to made changes on the code, but I am fairly new to this types of commands. Could you please give me the new coding lines to put into my VBA ? I think the reason why I used ODBC is because I have to specify my credentials to establish the connection but I am happy to proceed in a different way.

Comment: Alas, I haven't had to use ADO/VBA in a very long time, so whipping up working code is too challenging -- I have no way to even test it. I hope there are badge holders with more active experience on the site.

Comment: Please share the parameter declaration of your stored procedure. I believe the most likely causes of the error are either using the wrong order for the parameters, or the wrong type.

Comment: Hi Erik, Please see below all parameters definition. Can you please help me ? Thanks !!

Comment: I can't remember the error message I was getting long ago when I worked with stored procs in Access via ODBC, but I remember the solution, so it might be worth a try for you. Add `SET NOCOUNT ON` as the first line of your stored procedure. As I recall, the rows affected message made Access angry and setting NOCOUNT suppresses that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use calling raw text for sql command

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "ODBC;Description=RiskManager;DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;SERVER=APX-TEST01;UID=X.Tran;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=RiskManager;"
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = "Exec GetPortfolioLookthroughMultiPeriod   @PORTFOLIONAME ='wefb' ,@DATE= '2018-02-06' , @TYPES='portfolio' ,@VALUES = 'portfolio' ,@ISLOOKTHROUGH=1 ,@PORTFOLIOCURRENCY='PC' ,@EXPRISKLEVEL='currency' ,@NUMBEROFMONTHS=15 ,@AssetClassStrategyName='fund' ,@NUMBEROFPERIODS=1 ,@FREQUENCY='d' ,@ShowDetail=1 ,@TableNo=6"
    .CommandTimeout = 0
    .Execute
End With
```

Disadvantage is that you won't get results, but you'll get your command executed